# How to add many child objects for a HABTM self-reference in Factory Girl Rails/Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

In the `Project` model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :subprojects,
  :join_table => "project_projects"
```

In a Cucumber feature file:

```
Given the following projects exist:
| name   | type |
| first  | foo  |
| second | bar  |
| third  | baz  |
| fourth | bar  |
Given the following subprojects exist:
| subproject | superproject |
| first      |              |
| second     | first        |
| third      | first        |
| third      | second       |
...
And I add a superproject "second" to "fourth"
And I add a superproject "third" to "fourth"
```

In other words, `third` has *two* parents, `first` and `second`, and `fourth` initially has *no* parents, but some are added for the purposes of a single scenario. How do we create the factories for this in Factory Girl Rails? We already have a `:project` factory, but there's no `Project_project` model, for obvious reasons, and we obviously don't want to create new projects every time we add a relation - We need to **reuse the existing objects in the subproject<->superproject factory.**